# Changing Spatial Reference System (SRS) of existing GeoTiff file?

Tags: coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff

How do I change the Spatial Reference System (SRS) of an existing GeoTiff file?

Or more fully, what can I use to convert the meta data for the file to a different SRS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just edit the metadata, use gdalmove with a huge pixel error tolerance (-et) setting.

If you want to translate a basically correct file into something other than the SRS it currently has, use gdalwarp.

Comment: Dam! I missed that on http://www.gdal.org/gdal_utilities.html.  I had scanned the page and completely failed to see it.

Comment: Pay attention also to gdal_edit.py.